# Maven build hangs after running testng tests

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to build my selenium  + testng test project using maven 3.0.4. I  run the command 'mvn verify' which runs the testng tests, but after that maven hangs,I do not get a build  success / failure confirmation message. What am I doing wrong ?

Following is the output of my maven command

```
Running TestSuite:

Tests run: 5, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 48.653 sec - in TestSuite
```

This is where my maven hangs

Following is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.global.search.tool</groupId>
  <artifactId>gst.acceptance</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>gst.acceptance</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>  
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>    
    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.17</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>  
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.17</version>
                <configuration>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>${basedir}/testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                    <skip>false</skip>
                </configuration>
                  <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>                        
        </plugins>
    </build>    
    <dependencies>      
            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <version>4.11</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
                <artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
                <version>2.40.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
                <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
                <version>2.40.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
                <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
                <version>2.40.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
                <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
                <version>6.8</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
                <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
                <version>2.40.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
                <artifactId>selenium-ie-driver</artifactId>
                <version>2.40.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-math3</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                <version>1.7.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                <version>1.7.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
                <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
                <version>3.9</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
                <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
                <version>3.9</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.5</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.github.goldin</groupId>
                <artifactId>mail-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.2.5</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
                <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.01</version>
           </dependency>            
    </dependencies>    
</project>
```

Comment: Are you running from command line ? What does `but after that maven hangs,` exactly mean? Have you tested only with a single tests are you correctly doing a shutdown in Selenium?

Comment: Yes I am running from commandline.I mean to say,after the testng tests have executed and the results are displayed in the commandline(as per the text pasted above), the maven prompt does not come back with a build success / failure message. It just stops after that line,keeps on waiting for something. I am doing a teardown in my testng test, where I close te browser - thats pretty much I do for shutdown.

Comment: @khmarbaise  : Got the problem. The maven build was hanging due to call to an exe file as part of the test as follows Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Users\\esaiqua\\Desktop\\Script.exe"); Once I comment out the call to this exe in my test, the maven build goes through successfully. Now the problem is that, this exe actually handles a http modal login pop-up in my application and if I comment it out, test will fail due to non login.